# Accessing internal service remotely while connected to Cloudflare WARP

Tags: vpn, cloudflare

I'm living in a place with heavy censorship ongoing including YouTube and Twitter. What I'm trying to achieve is:

Setup a SNI proxy server which with help of a self-hosted DNS server will redirect my connections to go through a publicy available VPS.
Being very satisfied with Cloudflare's WARP, So I thought I could install it on my server and with the combination of these two, I could access services mentioned by simply setting my custom DNS servers.

This happens to work nicely in my home network where I can flawlessly access these services, eg on my TV. The problem is that when I do the same on the VPS, ports 53 and 443 which I use for the DNS server and SNI proxy respectively, can't be accessed when the WARP client connects. Digging some more, I came across split tunnelling and no matter what I tried, it always fails, which is expected as I don't have any experience with stuff that technical. Is it possible I have my outgoing traffic go through WARP while allowing incoming traffic as normal? (Supposing my server's IP being X.Y.Z.T)